# Making an "enter" into a string in java

Tags: java, string, str-replace, stringtokenizer, projects

This may seem like a bit of a strange question, but I want to make an "enter" keystroke into a string.  I made a rather basic program to scan my papers (that I write for school) to find things such as prepositions at the end of a sentence or contractions I may have accidentally added.  My issue is, when i put the paper into my code, it try to tokenize all the sentences at periods.  When it reaches the point where I hit "enter" to move to the next line, it breaks and stops tokenizing.  I thought of maybe making "enter" into a string so that i could replace it with a space, but I can't figure out how to get the effects of an "enter" into a string.  Is there another way to stop the "enters" from breaking my code?

Sum up:
I enter my paper into my code and the effects of hitting "enter" in the paper cause the code to err.  I want to be able to enter the paper and have the code ignore the effects of the "enter."

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Presumably you're looking for `\n` or `\r\n` but without [an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) this question is incredibly unclear.

Comment: Can you post the source code here so that it can be debugged more easily?

Comment: `enter` is another way of saying `new line`. You're looking for `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

In java, "enters" are considered new lines. There are several ways to combat your problem. The most simple way is to compare each index of the string with the '\n' char which denotes a new line.

Please post a sample code of your problem if the problem persists. It is easier to correct issues when someone can see exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

I would not look for just `\n\` or `\r\n` as the line feed can be different from computer to computer, especially with different OS.

I would use the [System Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) to get the specified line feed you need:

```
String enterKey = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

This gets the sequence used by operating system to separate lines in text files